# Cohomological dimension of a group via infinite direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $R$ be a ring and $G$ an infinite group. The $R$-cohomological dimension of $G$ can be defined as $cd_R(G) = \min \{ n \geq 0 : H^{n+1}(G, R[G]) = 0\}$, which implies that $H^i(G, M) = 0$ for all $i > cd_R(G)$ and any $R[G]$-module $M$.

Here $R[G]$ denotes the group ring, which as a module is simply the direct sum of copies of $R$ indexed by $G$, with the action of $G$ permuting the coordinates. Denote instead by $R(G)$ the direct *product* of copies of $R$ indexed by $G$ with the same action (is there a standard notation?). This is not a ring anymore but it is still an $R[G]$-module, and so we can ask when does $H^n(G, R(G)) = 0$.

My question is,can we use this module to compute the cohomological dimension instead? That is, does $cd_R(G) = \min \{ n \geq 0 : H^{n+1}(G, R[G]) = 0\}$? Or what are some examples in which this does not hold? Does it hold under some finiteness hypothesis on the group (say, finitely generated, finitely presented...)

In case it helps I am interested in particular in the case in which $R$ is finite, or even a finite field, and $n = 1$.

Comment: You can write the direct product as $R^{|G|}$. As a module it's the $R$-linear dual of $R[G]$.

Comment: I don't think the first paragraph is accurate when $G$ has infinite $R$-cohomological dimension.

Comment: You mean, it's possible that $H^n(G, R[G]) = 0$ for some $n \geq 1$ but $cd_R(G) = \infty$?

Comment: Yes. For example, if $G$ has a subgroup of finite index with finite $R$-cohomological dimension, then $H^n(G,R[G])=0$ for all but finitely many $n$, but $G$ has infinite $R$-cohomological dimension unless $|G|$ is invertible in $R$.

Comment: I see, but it is true when $G$ is already known to have finite cohomological dimension?

Comment: You may need more than that: I'm not sure.

Comment: You need the group to also be of finite type, which means the group must have a finite classifying space (more generally the group can be of type $\mathrm{FP}_n(R)$ and this definition of cohomological dimension is true). In general, $\mathrm{cd}_R(G) = \sup\{n : \mathrm{H}^n(G; L) \neq 0 \ \text{and $L$ is a free $R[G]$-module}\}$ is the best definition you can hope for for groups of finite cohomological dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H^n(G,R(G))$ is *always* zero for $n>0$.

As Qiaochu Yuan pointed out in comments, $R(G)=\operatorname{Hom}_R(R[G],R)$. So $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R[G]}(?, R(G))\!=\operatorname{Hom}_{R[G]}(?,\operatorname{Hom}_R(R[G],R))=\operatorname{Hom}_R(?\otimes_{R[G]}R[G],R)=
\operatorname{Hom}_R(?,R).$$

So this shows that, calculating $H^n(G,R(G))=\operatorname{Ext}^n_{R[G]}(R,R(G))$ by applying $\operatorname{Hom}_{R[G]}(?, R(G))$ to a projective $R[G]$-module resolution of $R$, it is isomorphic as an $R$-module to $\operatorname{Ext}^n_R(R,R)$, which is zero for $n>0$.